# Why isn't Oracle's Order By Working Properly?

Tags: sql, oracle

So basically I'm running this SQL oracle program and I want to print 5 rows and have them ordered based on average rating.  So far I have 2 issues: it keeps printing duplicate values and it's not ordered by rating.

The tables are as follows:

```
Title_basics
----------------------
Primarytitle NVARCHAR2(950)
Genres NVARCHAR2(350)
Endyear VARCHAR2(4)


Title_ratings
--------------------------------------
Averagerating Number(5,2)
```

```
COLUMN Title FORMAT a30 HEADING Title
COLUMN Genres FORMAT a20 HEADING Genres
COLUMN Rating FORMAT 99.99 HEADING Rating
COLUMN Year FORMAT a7 HEADING Format

SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT tb.primarytitle AS Title, tb.genres AS Genres, tr.averagerating AS Rating, tb.endyear AS Year
                FROM title_basics tb, title_ratings tr
                WHERE tb.genres LIKE '%Comedy%' AND (tb.endyear = '2001' OR tb.endyear = '2002' OR tb.endyear = '2003' OR tb.endyear = '2004' OR tb.endyear = '2005')
                ORDER BY tb.endyear DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 5;
```

Comment: Why would it be ordered by ratings, when your `ORDER BY` clause is by `tb.endyear`???

Comment: Okay yeah that fixed it, I'm dumb, thanks

Comment: So this is basically a silly mistake of ordering by the wrong column?

Comment: BTW, are you aware of [the `IN` condition](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm)?

Comment: Am I missing something?  I'm not seeing any kind of join condition between the two tables.  Nor do I even see a column in Title_ratings that would even _allow_ a join. This will create a Cartesian join - where _every_ row in one table will be joined to _every_ row in the other.

Answer (score 1):

Put order by clause outside of your subquery -

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT tb.primarytitle AS Title, tb.genres AS Genres, tr.averagerating AS Rating, tb.endyear AS Year
                FROM title_basics tb, title_ratings tr
                WHERE tb.genres LIKE '%Comedy%' AND (tb.endyear = '2001' OR tb.endyear = '2002' OR tb.endyear = '2003' OR tb.endyear = '2004' OR tb.endyear = '2005')
                
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 5
ORDER BY Year DESC
```

Comment: I've tried that but tb.endyear is an invalid identifier because it's outside the FROM clause.

Comment: Actually, according to [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm), the query in the question is correct.

Comment: This also would cause to order the 5 selected rows, not to limit the ordered result...

Comment: @Jish, Could you please provide some sample data and your expected output in table format

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FETCH` clause to specify the number of rows to return. It is a lot more flexible than ROWNUM ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6))

```
SELECT DISTINCT tb.primarytitle     AS title,
                tb.genres           AS genres,
                tr.averagerating    AS rating,
                tb.endyear          AS year
  FROM title_basics   tb,
       title_ratings  tr
 WHERE tb.genres LIKE '%Comedy%' AND
       ( tb.endyear = '2001' OR
         tb.endyear = '2002' OR
         tb.endyear = '2003' OR
         tb.endyear = '2004' OR
         tb.endyear = '2005' )
 ORDER BY tb.averagerating DESC
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question really makes no sense.  You have no join columns in the average ratings table.  Presumably, there is a column that ties it back to the other table:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT tb.primarytitle AS Title, tb.genres AS Genres, tr.averagerating AS Rating, tb.endyear AS Year
      FROM title_basics tb JOIN
           title_ratings tr
           ON tb.? = tr.?   -- presumably some JOIN condition here
      WHERE tb.genres LIKE '%Comedy%' AND 
            tb.endyear IN ('2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005')
      ORDER BY tr.averagerating DESC
     ) br
WHERE ROWNUM <= 5;
```

The `?` is for the columns that specify the `JOIN` conditions.

If you join the tables correctly, then you probably don't need `SELECT DISTINCT`.